# UIImagePickerController for multiple buttons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

I have 4 UIButtons and 4 UIImgeViews and each button should change image of its UIImageView using UIImagePickerController. Button #1 should change imageview #1 and so on. all should be different.
It works fine with just the first button and imageview but I'm not sure how to apply it for all 4.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

UIImage *image1 = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];


NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1);
NSString *myGrabbedImage = @"myGrabbedImage.png";
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fullPathToFile = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:myGrabbedImage];

[data writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:YES];
[[self firstImageView]setImage:image1];


[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

I know this only sets a picture to the first imageView but how can I do it for all 4 ?

Comment: I have to be misunderstanding this question. Why is the answer not `[[self secondImageView]setImage:image1];` and so on?

Comment: If I do so then the picture i choose apply to all imageView´s

Comment: Well, what image do you want to apply to the other imageViews?

Comment: button #1 should open imagepickercontroller so that picture should change imageview #1, and so on. so different in every

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button-pressed code can leave a value lying around to say which button is being dealt with:

```
- (void) buttonPressed:(id)sender {
      imageViewBeingEdited = sender.imageView;
      // display image picker here
}
```

then

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    imageViewBeingEdited.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    ...
}
```

Comment: ok but the "imageViewBeingEdited" part, is that a variable? it says that I has to declare it first.

Comment: Yes, it's an instance variable, specific to the instance of the class of objects you're creating here. Declare it like this: `@implementation MyClassName { UIImageView imageViewBeingEdited; }` at  the top of the class you're writing.